# Are unused const/function of golang package included in executable binary?

Tags: function, go, methods, struct, constants

Are unused const/function/struct's method of golang package included in executable binary?

for example:

1. If I have a package `Const` which contains bunch of constants (containing SQL queries), but only few of them used in `main`, would it all included in the executable binary when compiled?

```
package Const
const (
   InsertA = `insert into ...` 
   InsertB = `insert into ...`
   UpdateA1 = `update ...` // certain column
   UpdateA2 = `update ...` // other columns, different where, etc..
   ...
)
// in main, only some of them used/prepared
```

2. If I have a package `Func` which contains bunch of functions returning literals (SQL strings), but only few of them used in `main`, would it all included in the executable binary when compiled?

```
package Func
func InsertA() string { return `insert into ...` }
func InsertB() string { return `insert into ...` }
func UpdateA() string { return `Update ...` }
...
```

3. If I have a package `mix`, which contains bunch of functions returning/using all constants like in number 1, but only some of the functions used in `main` would it all included in the executable binary when compiled?

```
package mix
const (
   insertA = `insert into ...`
   insertB = `insert into ...`
   updateA = `update ...`
   ...
)
func InsertA() string { return insertA }
func InsertB() string { return insertB }
func UpdateA() string { return updateA }
// in main, only some of the const are prepared
```

4. If I have a package `Struct`, which contains a lot of structs with bunch of methods (categorized SQL per table), but only some of the struct called in `main`, would all constant, struct definitions, methods included in the executable binary when compiled?

```
package Struct
const (
   insertA = `insert into ...`
   insertB = `insert into ...`
   updateA = `update ...`
   ...
)
// in main only some of them prepared
type A struct {db *DB}
func (a *A) Prepare() error {} 
func (a *A) InsertA(...) error {} 
func (a *A) UpdateA(...) error {} 
type B struct {db *DB}
func (b *B) Prepare() error {} 
func (b *B) InsertB(...) error {} 
// in main only some of them used (eg. only struct `A` used)
```

the context/case was for refactoring old codebase, so it can be better for debugging/understanding the code for new programmers (to know easily which functions/methods that modify that table by merging into one struct per table or one package per table) without sacrificing binary size, because currently all command-queries scattered in multiple binaries/packages (have to manually ctrl+F `INSERT INTO tablename` or `UPDATE tablename` or `DELETE FROM tablename` to look which functions/methods that write/modify records on that table).
So I can decide whether it better to have one package for each table (250+) or one single package with multiple files containing empty structs of each table.

old codebase was something like this:

```
package hugeX
func foo() map[constQ]string {
  return map[constQ]string{
    insertB: `insert into...`,
    updateA: `update ...`,
    ...
  }
}
package hugeY
func foo() map[constQ]string {
  return map[constQ]string{
    insertA: `insert into...`,
    updateB: `update ...`,
    ...
  }
}
package foo
const (
  insertB = `insert into..`
  updateA = `update ...`
  ...
)
package bar // importing hugeX
const ( 
  insertA = `insert into ...` 
  updateA = `update ...` // by something, sometimes duplicates
  ... 
)
package baz 
const (
  ...
)
... and so on..
```

Comment: This is an internal compiler implementation detail that may vary between compiler versions and targets. Regarding this code though, you might want to consider refactoring anyway. Packages should be oriented around functionality, not which language constructs they use; there should never be a package `const`, or `func`, or `struct`. Also package names should be all lowercase. This code will rapidly become impossible to maintain, and any other Go developer will have a very difficult time understanding it as is.

Comment: There was a question about this on the golang-nuts mailing list. The answer was that: the linker only includes functions that are referenced by main and all methods of all referenced types are included.

Comment: I second Adrian's recommendation to refactor the code.

Comment: that's just an example @Adrian

Comment: how about constants? @BurakSerdar

Comment: Usually constants are not included as separate entities in the binary. They are unaddressable constant values, not variables. How they are stored is an implementation decision though.

Comment: Indeed constants are not compiled into the binary at all. Wherever the constant name appears, the compiler replaces it with the constant's value. That's the point of constants.

Comment: whoa, so large string constants not merged into one reference? (unlike Ruby's symbol)

Comment: @Kokizzu Previous comments do not imply that the tool chain does not do constant value folding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after testing those and using `strings` and `grep`

```
strings binaryName | grep CONSTANTSPREFIX
strings binaryName | grep CONSTANTRETURNEDBYFUNCS
strings binaryName | grep CONSTANTRETURNEDBYMETHODS
```

the code something like this

```
package a
const (
   A0 = `ZAAA0` // use this on main
   A1 = `ZAAA1`
   A2 = `ZAAA2`
   A3 = `ZAAA3`
   A4 = `ZAAA4`
   A5 = `ZAAA5`
   A6 = `ZAAA6`
)
func B1() string { return A1 } // call this on main
func B2() string { return A2 }
func B3() string { return `ZBBB3` } // call this on main
func B4() string { return `ZBBB4` }
type C1 struct{}
func (c *C1) C3() string { return A3 } // call this on main
func (c *C1) C4() string { return A4 }
type D1 struct{}
func (c *D1) D5() string { return A5 }
func (c *D1) D6() string { return A6 }
```

the main:

```
package main
import "a"
import "fmt"
func main() {
        c := a.C1{}
        fmt.Println(a.A0,a.B1(),a.B3(),c.C3())
}
```

the result

```
$ go version
go version go1.15.6 linux/amd64
$ go build main.go
$ strings main | grep ZAAA
ZAAA0ZAAA1ZAAA3ZBBB3
```

only those that are called are included in the executable binary.

Comment: Methods and the constants referenced by the method are included in the executable if the method is called **or** the tool chain cannot prove that there is no access to the method through the reflect package.  Also note that the tool chain folds constant values.  Only one ZAAA0 is included in the executable when the print statement  changed to `fmt.Println(a.A0,a.B1(),a.B3(),c.C3(), "ZAAA0")`